# Injection Dependency of spring boot filter usage

Tags: java, spring-boot, filter, dependency-injection

I'm practicing spring boot API access token project and here is my question.

Here is my filter file and I'm trying to extends `OncePerRequestFilter` and inject three arg in to the filter using `@RequiredArgsConstructor` annotation.

```java
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class LogInFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

  private final OAuthService oAuthService;
  private final AccessTokenService accessTokenService;
  private final ObjectMapper mapper;
```

Here is the `@Bean`

```java
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig {

@Bean
  public FilterRegistrationBean logInFilter() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new LogInFilter());
    bean.addUrlPatterns("/test/api");
    bean.setOrder(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
    return bean;
  }
```

and I have no idea how to put this three arg as constructor in to new `LogInFilter()` above

Comment: Remove `newLoginFilter`. Rename method to `logInFilterRegistration` and use `LogInFilter` as an argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this

```java
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean logInFilterRegistration(LogInFilter logInFilter) {
  FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(logInFiliter);
  bean.addUrlPatterns("/test/api");
  bean.setOrder(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
  return bean;
}
```

Your filter is annotated with `@Component` so Spring will automatically create an instance, which you can use like this.